# What is the backport of Rails 3 style finders (.where) to Rails 2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-plugins, ruby-on-rails-2

I know I've heard of a library that provides Rails 3 style finders (`.where`) to earlier versions of Rails, but web search is failing me.

I've got a 2.3 project that needs a new feature, and I'd rather use the newer style in case it gets upgraded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Would something like the [Fake_arel](https://github.com/gammons/fake_arel) gem help?

`Fake_arel` simulates and supports a variety of features from Rails 3 for earlier Rails versions.  The only major requirement is that your currently-used ActiveRecord gem needs to be greater than or equal to version 2.3.5.

The documentation also notes that `Fake_arel` can be used as a bridge between Rails 2 and Rails 3 apps, which could ease future transitions to later Rails versions.